# Include join in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to make a query to obtain the last date time when a records repeat.

```
select * from OCCONTROLMERCADERIA om 
join OCCONTROLMERCADERIALINEAS oml on om.occontrolid=oml.occontrolid
where om.OCControlNroId=5519337
```

This return this:

[Result Query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai7Hm.png)

The query that i want should return the register are in the blue box.

I have this query that found (without the join):

```
with
    p as (select * from OCCONTROLMERCADERIA om where om.OCControlNroId=5519337),
    p_rnk as (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by OCControlNroId order by OCControlFecha desc) as rn
        from p
    )
select * from p_rnk where rn = 1 order by OCControlNroId;
```

This return this:

[Result Query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSlcf.png)

That its ok, if see the box blue in the first image, the last date corresponds to the record id 13756.

But I need that the query return the 3 records that corresponds to id 13756, and not only one, so i trying to apply the join.

```
with
    p as (select * from OCCONTROLMERCADERIA om 
    join OCCONTROLMERCADERIALINEAS oml on om.occontrolid=oml.occontrolid
    where om.OCControlNroId=5519337),
    p_rnk as (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by OCControlNroId order by OCControlFecha desc) as rn
        from p  
    )
select * from p_rnk where rn = 1 order by OCControlNroId;
```

But this return:

**The column 'OCControlId' was specified multiple times for 'p'.**

I´m trying this (select om.*):

```
with
    p as (select om.* from OCCONTROLMERCADERIA om 
    join OCCONTROLMERCADERIALINEAS oml on om.occontrolid=oml.occontrolid
    where om.OCControlNroId=5519337),
    p_rnk as (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by OCControlNroId order by OCControlFecha desc) as rn
        from p  
    )
select * from p_rnk where rn = 1 order by OCControlNroId;
```

And the error disappears but only return one records, no the three. Which could the problem ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This looks like TSQL to me and not mysql or, did mysql add CTEs and Windowing functions?

Comment: Sorry. I failed in the selection of the tags. Thanks!